# How to add the is operator to the datagrid mui filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I saw in the material ui "datagrid" documentation that for "countries" there was the "is" operator which gave the possibility to select a value (like the first tab here https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/)

I would like to add the "is" operator to all my columns to sort them and select a value from a list

I have seen that custom operator exist but i don't really understand how can I integrate it in my code

Here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useSearchBar } from '../hooks/useSearchBar';

export const TableReusable = ({ data, columns, bool, setSkillSelected }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const onRowsSelectionHandler = (ids) => {
    const selectedRowsData = ids?.map((id) =>
      data?.find((row) => row?._id === id || row?.id === id)
    );
    if (setSkillSelected) {
      dispatch(setSkillSelected(selectedRowsData));
    }
  };

  const filteredRows = useSearchBar({ row: data });

  return (
    <DataGrid
      sx={{ width: 'fit-content' }}
      rows={filteredRows}
      getRowId={(row) => row?.id || row?._id || row?.CommonId}
      columns={columns}
      initialState={{
        pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 10 } },
      }}
      onRowSelectionModelChange={(ids) => onRowsSelectionHandler(ids)}
      componentsProps={{
        pagination: {
          labelRowsPerPage: 'Nb par page',
        },
      }}
      pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 15, 20, 50, 100]}
      checkboxSelection={bool}
      components={{
        Toolbar: GridToolbar, //here i want to integrate my custom operator
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

this is my filter
[image]

Comment: If I understand what you want to do, you aren't interested in simply adding a ```filterModel``` to the filter in the initial state of the grid, but adding a custom operator for your filters. I found this link that might help you: [custom operators](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/customization/). It may also help to check how the ```data``` object returned from the ```useDemoData()``` function is structured.

Comment: That exactly what I want. adding the custom operator "is". Thank you, i will read and try this